Parsing NonEmptyList directly from JSON
Given this JSON: [{"name": "test"}].
Is there a way I can parse this JSON array directly into an Arrow NonEmptyList?
My background is Scala and I'm exploring Ktor + Arrow.
I have an endpoint I'd like to do something like: call.receive<NonEmptyList<DataClass>>().
It seems though since serialization is based on an annotation, without a data class with @Serializable it looks like it does not know how to parse the JSON even with @file:UseSerializers(NonEmptyListSerializer::class) on the file.

After some investigation, with the help of @nomisRev pointers, when using Ktor and installing the JSON serializer, this is what I've arrived at:
install(ContentNegotiation) {
    json(Json {
        serializersModule =
            SerializersModule { contextual(NonEmptyList::class) { args -> NonEmptyListSerializer(args[0]) } }
    })
}

https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/docs/serializers.md#contextual-serialization-and-generic-classes
This is being addressed in Arrow: https://github.com/arrow-kt/arrow/pull/3413

Arrow-kt has out-of-the-box support for KotlinX Serialization. It’s explained here in the documentation, https://arrow-kt.io/learn/quickstart/serialization/.
It can be added through maven coordinates io.arrow-kt:arrow-core-serialization:$version.
EDIT:
If you're not controlling the data class, but are polymorphically deserialising JSON you need to register the serialises in the SerializersModule. KotlinX uses reflection to find serializers, but it doesn't do classpath scanning so it cannot automatically detect NonEmptyListSerializer. @file only works when you add it in a file that defines the data class like you said.
So for KotlinX to find the polymorphic serializer, you need to use KotlinX Serializers Module. https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/docs/polymorphism.md#merging-library-serializers-modules
So in Ktor:
install(ContentNegotation) {
  json {
     serializersModule = SerializersModule {
       // register serialises
     }
  }
}


The documentation linked explains how to add the Arrow types to a data class annotated with @Serializable. I'm talking about when you don't have a data class, but want to parse a NonEmptyList directly.
If you try to do that, for example: Json.decodeFromString<NonEmptyList<String>>("""["test"]"""), you'll get kotlinx.serialization.SerializationException: Serializer for class 'NonEmptyList' is not found. even with @file:UseSerializers(NonEmptyListSerializer::class) at the top of the file.
What I'm trying to do in the end is use Ktor's call.receive<NonEmptyList<...>>.
